Random walk between 0 and 1 generating only 0 for cases lower than 0.5 as input
I am trying to write a function that takes a float between 0 and 1 (including 0 and 1) it then calculates the distances from both 0 and 1 and takes the minimum between the two to be the amount that it would walk.
The direction of movement is then decided by a fair coin toss. If the result is heads (1) the movement amount will be added to the input float. If the result is tails (0) the movement amount will be subtracted from the input float. This will be repeated until the input float reaches either 0 or 1.
If the float becomes 1 then a counter called 'Success' is incremented. The entire process is repeated a set number of times and the finally the function returns 'Success' divided by the number of itterations to get a probability of the input float resulting in a 1.
I then divide the range 0 to 1 into 1024 evenly spaced points. Each of these is then given to the function and the inputs and outputs are stored. This is then plot with Seaborn with the input being on the X-axis and the output on the Y-axis.
I expected this to produce a line that roughly follows y = x since that is statistically what should happen. Instead I get this: Probability of Success vs X_Start with 1024 points.
This is my code:
from random import random, choice
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gc

def Experiment(X_Start) -> float:
    Num_Trials = 1000
    Success = 0

    for Trial in range(Num_Trials):
        X_Current = X_Star
        Movement_Radius = min(X_Start, 1 - X_Start)

        while 0 < X_Current < 1:
            if choice([0, 1]):
                X_Current += Movement_Radius
            else:
                X_Current -= Movement_Radius

        if X_Current == 1:
            Success += 1

    return Success / Num_Trials, X_Start

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = {'X_Start': [], 'Probability': []}
    n = 5

    for i in range(0, 2**n+1):
        Probability, X_Initial = Experiment(i/2**n)
        results['X_Start'].append(X_Initial)
        results['Probability'].append(Probability)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)

    plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='X_Start', y='Probability', marker='x', color='red')
    plt.xlabel('X_Start')
    plt.ylabel('Probability of Success')
    plt.title(f'Probability of Success vs X_Start with {2**n} points')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

I am not sure why this is happening.

You are checking for a result of exactly 1, but that is an extremely unlikely result for a random walk.  You're only getting significant successes above 0.5, because only in that case can 1 be reached in a single step, which is the only likely scenario where 1 is reached exactly.  The success check needs to be X_Current >= 1.

"1024 evenly spaced points" - You mean 1025?

What actually happens is NameError: name 'X_Star' is not defined..

Floating point number are imprecise. Comparing floats with == will give unexpected results quite often.
In your case, you will (almost) never hit exactly 1.
Try something like if X_Current >= 1: to test for success.

Try something like... exactly what they have?

I am assuming you meant 'if X_Current >= 1:'
I did that and it worked thank you for pointing it out! I now see there are some other bugs, but I will try and fix them myself before asking about them (I also don't know how to express the problem yet).

I got it completely fixed! I had to move 'Movement_Radius = min(X_Start, 1 - X_Start)' into the while loop and change it to 'Movement_Radius = min(X_Current, 1 - X_Current)'.

I very much disagree that this bug is due to floating point imprecision and that comparing them with == often gives unexpected results.
